# USB drive stop working while is in use

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

First of all i'm sorry for my english.

I post here because i've searched a long time in google and i've not found anything useful. I've seen some post on this forum too but all are too old or don't solve anything.

Well my problem is with an external USB drive: I've a Debian wheezy Server full updated with kernel 3.2.0-4-686-pae, and i've bought an USB drive to extend it storage.
The problem is when i start to copy a lot of files to external storage, then the drive stop working. I've seen that drive continues mounted but it becomes unresponsive and the only way to get it working is disconnecting the USB and then reconnecting again.

The USB drive is a Seagate Expansion Desktop 2TB 3.5" USB3.0 with external power supply.

The syslog shows this:

```
Jul 18 10:57:38 SomeServer kernel: [163444.176034] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
Jul 18 10:57:38 SomeServer kernel: [163444.300025] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jul 18 10:57:38 SomeServer kernel: [163444.528031] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jul 18 10:57:39 SomeServer kernel: [163444.744043] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
Jul 18 10:57:39 SomeServer kernel: [163444.868054] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jul 18 10:57:39 SomeServer kernel: [163445.096045] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jul 18 10:57:39 SomeServer kernel: [163445.312044] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163445.724044] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 12, error -71
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163445.836063] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248060] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 12, error -71
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248133] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248152] sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248179] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248184] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248192] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 16 c3 7a 2a 00 00 1e 00
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248211] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3055276368
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248244] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909290
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248278] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248286] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909291
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248320] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248328] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909292
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248359] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248366] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909293
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248402] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248408] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909294
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248437] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.248443] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909295
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249782] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249790] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909296
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249820] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249826] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909297
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249855] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249861] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909298
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249889] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249895] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 381909299
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249923] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.249997] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.250002] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.250010] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 16 c3 7a 48 00 00 1e 00
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.250028] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3055276608
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.346073] JBD: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.346259] journal_bmap: journal block not found at offset 16396 on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.346302] Aborting journal on device sdc1.
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.346375] JBD: I/O error detected when updating journal superblock for sdc1.
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.346433] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.346579] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374086] JBD: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sdc1
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374142] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_frozen_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374147] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_frozen_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374151] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_frozen_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374154] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_committed_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374158] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_frozen_data
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.374190] journal commit I/O error
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.394650] EXT3-fs (sdc1): error: ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
Jul 18 10:57:40 SomeServer kernel: [163446.394724] EXT3-fs (sdc1): error: remounting filesystem read-only
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.820598] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.820722] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.820817] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.820910] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821006] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821101] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821194] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821290] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821386] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821480] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821578] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821669] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821765] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821864] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.821962] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822059] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822157] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822254] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822351] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822454] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822556] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822648] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822740] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822847] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.822950] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.823041] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.823144] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #93773868 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.823632] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92577799 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.831563] __journal_remove_journal_head: freeing b_frozen_data
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.840980] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.841033] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.863650] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.865293] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.865900] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.903243] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.912264] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.927942] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.928606] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.929807] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.933678] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.935572] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.936040] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.936901] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.937351] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.939195] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.939678] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.940349] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.940860] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.941317] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.941758] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.942208] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.942617] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.943089] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.943557] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.944000] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.944757] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.945234] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.945651] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.946142] EXT3-fs error (device sdc1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #92561409 offset 0
Jul 18 10:57:41 SomeServer kernel: [163446.952110] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
```

I've tried to change the USB port, delete the partition and repartitioning with fdisk again, EXT3 and EXT4 format... and i don't know if is a Linux problem or maybe the USB drive is defective.

Yesterday i was able to copy about 170GB without problem, then i tried to copy a file of about 68GB and it started to fail.

Someone knows what can be failing?. I want to know it before replacing the unit with a new unit and continue having problems.

Thanks!!

Comment: When I had a external drive that presented this problems, turned out, the power supply wasn't working.

Comment: But full fail or intermitent?, because this drive can't work without external power supply.

Comment: It came with a power supply, it worked, then it didn't and presented problems similar to this. Does it matter if it was full or intermitent and I replacd the power supply and the problem was solved.   I replaced the power supply under warranty.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to send it back to shop. It has four days, then is in warranty too ;)

Answer (score 1):

"`Buffer I/O error`" unfortunately in most cases when it happened it was a hardware failure. To narrow the problem down you can try to boot up with Live CD/USB.

UPDATE:

You can try to treat this drive with `Gparted` and/or `fdisk`. [Gparted](http://gparted.org/) has also its own [Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

Comment: I can't try with a live CD :S. Is an external server and no one can do it there. Maybe i'll try to change the USB drive with a new one in shop.

Comment: You don't need to boot up that server namely with Live, I meant put this drive in any other computer, thaw would cover a number of potential issues,

Comment: I'll try to full format and copy with a Windows 7 PC.